# Android- Increasing text size in text view smoothly

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview

I want to **increase/decrease** the text size in text view but not by `.setTextSize()` method . Like when I click a button the size must change from one to another smoothly and not abruptly. The transition must be visible as it is increasing so that a good `UI` experience is obtained. I tried to use a loop where the size changes by small-small bits but thats also to quick to be visible. So please someone suggest me a method to do this. I am just a beginner in Android

Comment: Can you post your code from what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

This could be achieved with a `ValueAnimator`.

**Try this :**

```
final TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
Button btnPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
btnPlay.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);


final float startSize = 42; // Size in pixels
final float endSize = 12;
final int animationDuration = 600; // Animation duration in ms

ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(startSize, endSize);
animator.setDuration(animationDuration);

animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
        float animatedValue = (float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
        tv.setTextSize(animatedValue);
    }
});

@Override
public void onClick(View view)
{
   if(view == btnPlay)
   {
         animator.start();
   }
}
```

Use this code in on click listner of button, where you want to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform this using `View Animation.`
You should refer it from [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html)

create one `textanim.xml`  inside tour `res/anim` folder. (here add anim folder first in res file if not created.)

your `textanim.xml` should be look like this.

```
<set android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <scale
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="1.4"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="0.6"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:duration="700" />
    <set android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">
        <scale
           android:fromXScale="1.4"
           android:toXScale="0.0"
           android:fromYScale="0.6"
           android:toYScale="0.0"
           android:pivotX="50%"
           android:pivotY="50%"
           android:startOffset="700"
           android:duration="400"
           android:fillBefore="false" />
        <rotate
           android:fromDegrees="0"
           android:toDegrees="-45"
           android:toYScale="0.0"
           android:pivotX="50%"
           android:pivotY="50%"
           android:startOffset="700"
           android:duration="400" />
    </set>
</set>
```

Moving on to the associated java file (inside your Activity), you have to use this animation like this,

```
TextView mT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewId);
Animation myAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.textanim);
mText.startAnimation(myAnim);
```